# How to get particular textview's value from listview that is made up of Hashmap?

Tags: java, android

I am using `HashMap` to store data in list view and I am having two `TextView` in `ListView`. No I want only one of the textview's value. how could I get it by `onItemClick()` method?

Here is the code I have tried:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

                String mp =map.get(position);
                String str_Title = map.get(position);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the onItemClick Event:

```
HashMap<String, String> mymap = (HashMap<String, String>) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
String str_Title = mymap.get(<KEY>);
```

Simple.

Comment: what is the `(<KEY>)` there?

Comment: When you create the listview with multiple columns, you need to add a hashmap, the hashmap need a key string and a value, the key string is of reference in order for you to call it later. <KEY> here means add the used key for this cell.

Answer (score 0):

Trying in this way:--

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
                long arg3) {
            String mp =map.get(position).yourvalue;
                        String str_Title = map.get(position).title;

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

A `HashMap` requires objects for its keys and values. `position` is an `int` and thus not an `Object` and cannot be used as key or value.

To use integers as key, you need to convert them to `Integer` objects:

```
int index = 1;
map.put(Integer.valueOf(index), myObject);
```

and to grab the object:

```
map.get(Integer.valueOf(position));
```

Answer (score 0):

view should be the row view with the two textview, probably you can retrieve one of them using
`TextView txt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.your_text_view)`